# Does upgrading Ubuntu 10.04 will affect Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, 10.04

I have a dual-boot computer, which I want to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 (using the update manager) to another version.
Does it will affect the other operative system (Windows 7) and its data?

Comment: No it won't...  **Please update to a more recent version!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade will only cover the files contained in your ubuntu partition so nop it's not going to affect your windows 7.